# Conditional compilation (multiple app versions) in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a React app based on Create React App where I can build different versions of the app from a single code base (think of: branded UI, some functionality being available in one version but not in the other, etc.)

Is there a way to achieve conditional compilation (for example based on an env var) so that undesired/unused parts can be left out of the build?

Note, I am aware of dynamic imports but that's not what I am after. I don't want resources to be loaded dynamically at runtime: I want to be able to control what is included at build time.